# Typescript check if string is empty as boolean

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion, conventions

Is there a "proper" way to check if a string is empty in typescript, and return the answer as a boolean? In JavaScript, I typically just use the fact that an empty string is false, but Typescript doesn't like to convert between the types. There's quite a few ways of doing it that Typescript is fine with, but I was just curious is there's a "standard" way of doing things.

For example,

```
const emptyString: string = '';
const nonEmptyString: string = 'something';

function stringIsEmpty(str: string): boolean {
    return str; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
}
```

To fix it, we could do any of the following (and others), but they all feel kind of "hacky" in my opinion:

`return !!str;`

`return Boolean(str);`

`return str.length > 0;`

`return /^$/.test(str);`

Comment: Why not just `return str === ''` from `stringIsEmpty` if you intend to treat it as a boolean? This will return you an actual boolean as a consequence of the appropriate runtime check.

Comment: @Jeffrey Westerkamp That is an excellent point, don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

You could also cast it as boolean:

```
return str as unknown as boolean;
```